# How to work with RBAC in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I do understand RBAC and I'm able to create a role using rules en subjects, bind them with a user.

For example this role can only list the pods

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: development
  name: list-pods
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

Now we are using namespaces for every environment we have (dev, staging, prd). Now how do I have to provide this role to users in different namespaces? Do I have to create a clusterRole and bind it with a normal rolebinding or do I have to write the above .yaml once for dev, once for uat and once for prd? Are there somewhere rules written about how to handles those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now how do I have to provide this role to users in different namespaces?

You do if you want to be able to constrain the ability to list `Pod`s for that `Subject` on a per `Namespace` basis. For example, you might not want people to be able to see `Pod`s in `kube-system` (or a hypothetical `internal-security` namespace). Using the ability to list `Pod`s as an example makes this hard to imagine, but the ability to list, or view, or both, `Secret`s or `ConfigMap`s may make this more tangible. Presumably a `Subject` can view `Secret`s for their *own* project -- or even maybe not -- but not for other projects within the company. That kind of thing.

That gets even more real when one thinks about the ability to `exec` into arbitrary `Pod`s -- because that's the biggest risk that I can think of to the safety and confidentiality of applications in the cluster.

> Do I have to create a clusterRole and bind it with a normal rolebinding

No, one uses a `ClusterRoleBinding` for that purpose. "Have to" is not the right question; it depends on whether you want the binding to apply to all namespaces, current **and future**.

> or do I have to write the above .yaml once for dev, once for uat and once for prd?

That also depends on whether those `Namespaces` have identical risk and identical `Subject`s who access them.

> Are there somewhere rules written about how to handles those cases?

Definitely not; there's not one-size-fits-all for cluster security. It all depends on the kind of risk one is trying to drive down.

As a for-your-consideration, you're not obligated to use the RBAC constraints: you can certainly create a `ClusterRoleBinding` for every `Subject` to the `cluster-admin` `ClusterRole` and voilà, no more permission management. No more safeguards, either, but that's the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case I would create a single cluster role with the desired permissions and then bind it via role bindings to the appropriate subjects in the relevant namespaces.